# Number that can't be root of -1 quadratic residue modulo p

Tags: quadratic-residues

Every root of $−1$ quadratic residue modulo $p$ prime, $p=1(\mod4)$ is distinct.

Running tests it appears that some values are never root of $−1$ quadratic residue modulo $p$.

For exemple : $7, 18, 21, 38, 41$ etc.

Is there a way to "predict" which number will never be a root ?

Best regards.

Comment: Do you want numbers $x$ such that $0 < x < p$ ? If not, then $p=5$ works for $x=7$.

Comment: Your question looks like it was cut and pasted (poorly) from elsewhere.  Please edit.  Also, the question is unclear.  for any $x$ there is some prime $p$ such that $x^2\equiv -1 \pmod p$ (just take any $p$ which divides $x^2+1$.).

Comment: Yes the numbers x are 0<x<p.

Comment: This question is not a copy / paste from elsewhere, it's a question i ask myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to be:

> Which $n$ are not square roots of $-1$ mod $p$ for some prime $p > n$ ?

This is the same as

> Which $n$ have the property that the largest prime factor of $n^2+1$ is less than $n$ ?

The sequence of such $n$ is listed at OEIS as [A256011](http://oeis.org/A256011). Nothing much seems to be known about it.